# NoReverseMatch not a registered namespace, django 1.4 issue

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-1.4

I am forced to use django 1.4 to use neo4j, and I am getting a strange message that "accounts" isn't a registered namespace. It most certainly is, right there in the root:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
]
```

in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
    'accounts',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), )
```

in project root I have templates/accounts/index.html, which looks right because template_dirs points to that folder. It specifically complains at:

```
return render(request, 'accounts/index.html', locals())
```

which isn't returning a namspace, it's returning a template name starting at the templates folder. In case it's relevant, in the accounts app (which is installed), I have:

urls.py-

```
from django.conf.urls   import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib     import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('accounts.views',
    url(r'^$',                                      'index',                    name='index'),
    url(r'^register/$',                             'register',                 name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$',                                'user_login_page',          name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',                               'user_logout',              name='logout'),

)
```

Why is something that has a namespace causing NoReverseMatch not a registered namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to top of your base html.

```
{% load url from future %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 1.4 and it seems other older versions, `{% url 'accounts:register' %}` wasn't allowed...it only takes `{% url accounts:register %}`